# Is it possible to find a parabola knowing the average value.

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

My question: Is it possible to find a specific parabola when you know the average value, and the x intercepts? The parabola I am trying to find has x intercepts at 0 and 18 with an average value of 2.34

Can you reverse engineer the parabola using an average value equation?

Comment: Do you mean the area under the parabola from $0$ to $18$ is $18\times2.34$?

Comment: I'm assuming by average value you mean average value between the roots. Notice that if a parabola has roots $r_1,r_2$ its equation is $f(x)=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$ and its average value is
$$\frac{a}{r_2-r_1}\int_{r_1}^{r_2}(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Yes I meant between the roots, thanks for all the comments helped allot!

Answer (score 0):

In a slightly different notation from @K.defaoite's comment:

If $A>0$ and $a<b$, the parabola $y=A(x-a)(b-x)$ has area from $x=a$ to $x=b$ given by$$A\int_a^b(-ab+(a+b)x-x^2)=A(b-a)^3/6,$$as can be computed easily with $y=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$. The average on this interval is $\mu=A(b-a)^2/6$, so $A=\frac{6\mu}{(b-a)^2}$.